# If two spheres are isometric, does there exist a bijective isometry $T:S\to S$ with $\|Tu-\alpha Tv\|_Y \leq \|u-\alpha v\|_X$ for all $\alpha>0?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Let 
$$(S,\|\cdot\|) = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: \|(x,y)\| =1\},$$
that is, $S$ is the collection of all norm one vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|.$

> **Question**: Let $\|\cdot\|_X$ and $\|\cdot\|_Y$ be two norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ be such that $(S,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and $(S,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ are isometric. 
>   Does there exist a bijective isometry $T:(S,\|\cdot\|_X)\to (S,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ such that 
>   $$\|Tu-\alpha Tv\|_Y \leq \|u-\alpha v\|_X$$
>   for all $u,v\in (S,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and all $\alpha>0?$

Note that the norms $\|\cdot\|_X$ and $\|\cdot\|_Y$ may be distinct.

I tried $\|(x,y)\|_X = |x|+|y|,$ $\|(x,y)\|_Y = \max\{|x|,|y|\}$ and 
$$T(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that $T$ is a rotation matrix. 
Clearly $T$ is a bijective isometry and satisfies the inequality.

However, I do not know whether the same holds for general $\|\cdot\|_X$ and  $\|\cdot\|_Y.$

Comment: What do you mean by isometry? An isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @0x539 Yes. Isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: So if $\|\cdot\|_2 = \|\cdot\|_Y = \frac12 \|\cdot\|_X$ there could be no such isometry because the unit circle can't get mapped to itself?

Comment: Or are there supposed to be two unit circles $S_X$ and $S_Y$?

Comment: Yes. There are two unit circles

Comment: @0x539 However, you are answering my question to specific norms, that is, $\|\cdot\|_2 = \|\cdot\|_Y = \frac{1}{2} \|\cdot\|_X.$

Comment: Clearly there's no isometry between the unit circle of, say, the Euclidean norm, and that of the $\ell^\infty$-norm, since for the latter, for given $x$ there are infinitely many points at distance $2$ from $x$ in the unit circle.

Comment: @YCor What I mean is that if two unit circles are isometric, can we find a specific bijective isometry that satisfies the inequality above.